# How do you change the default font size for tables?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I know how to change the default font for text boxes and shapes: Right click box/shape, then select "Set as Default Textbox/Shape".

But I cannot figure out how to do this for tables. I always get 18pt text.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/03/xml-hacking-default-table-text/

I dont' have time right now to copy that info here. If someone wants to do it, be my guest (create a new answer, I'll delete this one).